# What is the correct value to report for input data in this context?

Tags: transactions, etherscan

On this transaction: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xae2630cdfbd0ca5292d272343c35dc8094365f2ecdc5c262c5639e79683f74dc, the input data is parsed and displayed as 'fund'.

This is both correct and incorrect.

It is incorrect because there is no function in the 'to' contract (singularDTVToken) called 'fund.'
(https://etherscan.io/address/0xaec2e87e0a235266d9c5adc9deb4b2e29b54d009#code).

But there is a function called 'fund' in a related contract, and the 4byte encoding for 'fund()' is 0xb60d4288, which is the value of the input data. 
(Related contract is  called SNGLSCrowdFund: https://etherscan.io/address/0xbdf5c4f1c1a9d7335a6a68d9aa011d5f40cf5520#code.)

I think it's misleading to say that the input data resolves to 'fund' in this case. This suggests that a function called 'fund' was invoked on the contract, when in fact, it was not.

My question is this: Is it correct to report 'fund' in the context of a contract that has no 'fund' function. Wouldn't it be more accurate to indicate that the default function had actually been called? (And is it true that the default function would have been called in this case?)

Comment: I think this results from assuming that, because 4byte encodings are the same across all contracts, that they carry the same meaning across all contracts. They don't. The meaning of an encoding in the input data is dependent only on the contract receiving the transaction. If there is no corresponding function, then I'm pretty sure the default function (if it exists) gets called. I'm trying to confirm this. Plus, I think etherscan reporting it as such is at best misleading.

Comment: I suggest you contact Ethercan.io author directly regarding this. Furthermore suggest ways to discriminate calls and other contract transactions.

Comment: I think that EtherScan picked these 4 bytes signature then correlated them to another contract whose code contains `function fund()`.

Comment: While this is misleading, it's also probably not very common. The wording should probably be clarified to say that this *may* have been a call to `fund()`, but I'm not sure it's worth complicating the issue by checking the source to make sure the function exists. (For instance, a proxy contract may just pass the data on, so the user may be calling a `fund` methopd of a different contract).

Comment: Also, I'm voting to close as opinion-based, but if people think this warrants discussion, we can have a chat in meta.

Comment: Why close it. There's an important issue here. The main place people get information about transactions is reporting misleading information. That seems important to me.

Comment: @TjadenHess, You're actually wrong. In the case of a proxy contract the input data would have the 'execute' in the input data field. The 'fund', if that's what was called would be in the parameters to the execute function, so etherscan would report 'execute' not 'fund.'

Comment: Also, you say it's not that common. I'm finding that it's quite common. I can show you more examples if you want.

Comment: @XavierLeprêtreB9lab Yes. I think some front end is mistakenly sending a valid function call to the wrong contract. My second question above is what happens in this case. Does the default function get called?

Comment: It's quite possible to build a proxy contract that forwards all transactions, and doesn't conform to the ABI spec. Also, while I agree this is an interesting point, it's not really a question that can be answered factually, it's a matter of design and preference

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52896/discussion-between-thomas-jay-rush-and-tjaden-hess).